# $MSE(\hat{\theta}_3) = 6$?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, estimation

Let $\hat{\theta}_1$, $\hat{\theta}_2$ and $\hat{\theta}_3$ be the estimators of $\theta$. We know that $E(\hat{\theta}_1) = E(\hat{\theta}_2) = \theta$, $E(\hat{\theta}_3) \not= \theta$, $V(\hat{\theta}_1)=12$, $V(\hat{\theta}_2)=10$ and $E[(\hat{\theta}_3 - \theta)]^2 = 6$. Which one of the estimators do you prefer?

**Answer:** $MSE(\hat{\theta}_1) = 12$, $MSE(\hat{\theta}_2) = 10$ and $MSE(\hat{\theta}_3) = 6$. $\hat{\theta}_3$ is the best

I am very very confused. Why $MSE(\hat{\theta}_3) = 6$? This is true only if $E[(\hat{\theta}_3 - \theta)^2] = 6$, but this is not explicit this is true. For me, $E[(\hat{\theta}_3 - \theta)^2] \not= E[(\hat{\theta}_3 - \theta)]^2$

**EDIT:**

In my book,

- $MSE(\hat{\theta}) = E[(\hat{\theta} - \theta)^2] = V(\hat{\theta}) + [Bias(\hat{\theta})]^2$
- $Bias(\hat{\theta}) = E(\hat{\theta}) - \theta$

Comment: Are you sure you're not just quoting a typographical error?  Surely the original question meant to stipulate that $E[(\hat\theta_3-\theta)^2]=6.$

Comment: Yes, this is what I thought. It is an error in the book